# How to match rails route based on URL ending with an ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

It seems really easy to match routes using the '/' as a separator, but I'd like to match using a hyphen. Only problem is that there could be hyphens in the dynamic text that I want to appear before the ID:

Format:  http://www.cities.com/-
Example: http://www.cities.com/los-angeles-california-123

match '/:description-:id' => 'cities#show' does not work because the :description text can contiain ids.

Is there any way for me to match this format? I've done this before in .NET using Regex, but loving my new life as a Ruby Dev.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid using the routes for this: just pass the param :id and split it in the controller.
E.g.
`City.find param[:id].split('-').last`

More importantly make sure you are able to generate proper ulrs by overriding `to_param`in the model:

```
def to_param
  "#{self.name.split(' ').join('-')}-#{self.id}" # FIXME need extra sanity checks
end
```

One last trick, unless you do need the id as the last arg, you'd better put it at the beginning, e.g. `123-los-angeles`, this way you do not need to "parse" the id in your controller, `Model.find '123-los-angeles'` works out of the box.

Cheers,